# Validating an email textfield using a button extjs

Tags: validation, extjs, textfield

I have a textfield which takes email as its value by using

```
vtype : 'email'
```

I am trying to validate this textfield using a button, wherein, when clicked, it should alert me if the textfield has email input or not. Based on  my code, the validation always gives me **false** no matter the input. how should I do this? Here is my code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        id: 'emailField',
        fieldLabel: 'EmailAddress',
        vtype: 'email',
        allowBlank: false,
        validator: function (val) {
            var fieldValidation = Ext.form.field.VTypes.email(val);
            if (fieldValidation === true) {
                this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #BCF5A9");
            } else {
                this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #F6CECE");
            }
        },

    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'select',
        handler: function () {
            alert(Ext.getCmp('emailField').isValid());
        }
    }]
});
```

P.S: I understand that the problem is with the `validator: function (val)` I have used in the textfield. But I need it to change the color of the textfield based on the input. Is there any other way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

I got it working by changing the `validator : function` to a `change : function`

```
listeners: {
        'change': function (thisField) {

            if (thisField.isValid()) {
                this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #BCF5A9");
            } else {
                this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #F6CECE");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by changing the `validator : function` to a `change : function`

```
listeners: {
        'change': function (thisField) {

            if (thisField.isValid()) {
                this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #BCF5A9");
            } else {
                this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #F6CECE");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, your custom validator is messing up validation coming with default vtype:'email'. Remove the validator function and validation will work correctly.

If you just want to change the color of the textfield based on the validated input, all you need to do is override the css class (.x-form-invalid-field-default) which is added every time the textfield is invalid.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the theme is an issue only when i implement my code in fiddle.. not when i do it in my real program

Comment: yes. thank you.. i understand this way of doing it. but i am not supposed to use css for this. thats the biggest headache.

Comment: btw, thank u.. i got it working by changing validator to change